# How to select selected value multivalue in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

i want to get selected ids in activity which is selected in recyclerview adapter

```
holder.images.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (holder.checked.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {

                holder.checked.setVisibility(View.GONE);



            } else if (holder.checked.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {


                holder.checked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: 1. Use a SparseArray to store the selected positions
2. Update this SparseArray in the onClick / onLongClicked method to add/remove selected position, use notifyItemChanged(position) call to update the selected/unselected item.
3. Use the SparseArray to properly mark selected/unselected items in your onBindViewHolder() method of the adapter.
4. Provide a getter for this SparseArray in your adapter which can be utilized by the Activity.

Comment: you mean that when you click an item, you want to get selected position in your adapter and you want to use this position in activity, don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here that solution i created arrylist and put data size

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> dataSize=new ArrayList<>();
```

and pass to adapter

```
  holder.checked.setVisibility(idpositions.get(position)==0?View.GONE:View.VISIBLE);

    holder.images.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (dataSize.size()>0) {

                if (holder.checked.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {

                    holder.checked.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    dataSize.set(position,0);

                } else if (holder.checked.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {

                    dataSize.add(position,data.getId());

                    holder.checked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }

            }
        }
    });
```

and on button click simply get that arraylist and  get your selected value

```
  if(dataSize.size()>0){

        for (int i = 0; i < dataSize.size(); i++) {

            if (dataSize.get(i)==0){
                continue;
            }else {
                ids= ids+String.valueOf(dataSize.get(i))+",";
            }

        }

        Toast.makeText(this, ids, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use list to handle your selected items or positions

declare list for store selected items

```
private List<Integer> selectedPositions=new ArrayList();
```

update code in onBindViewHolder like below

```
holder.checked.setVisibility(selectedPositions.contains(position)?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE);
holder.images.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (selectedPositions.contains(position)) {
                    holder.checked.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                      selectedPositions.removeAt(selectedPositions.indexOf(position));
                    } else  {
                    holder.checked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    selectedPositions.add(position);

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: getting error

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:483)
        at cos.munchmash.Adpater.FoodieAdapter.FavouriteSubCategoryAdapter$1.onClick(FavouriteSubCategoryAdapter.java:56)

Answer (score 0):

Now, you need to declare a list to hold those selected ids

```
private List<DATA_TYPE> selectedIds = new ArrayList();
```

What you can do is declare one `isSelected` boolean in your model. In `onBindViewHolder` method, set visibility as

```
if (YOUR_POJO.isSelected()) {
   holder.checked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
   holder.checked.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

When you click on image check if it was already selected based on that you can add/remove its id

```
holder.images.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(YOUR_POJO.isSelected()){
             YOUR_POJO.setSelected(false);
             if (selectedIds.contains(YOUR_POJO.getId()){
                selectedIds.remove(YOUR_POJO.getId());
             }
        } else {
             YOUR_POJO.setSelected(true);
             selectedIds.add(YOUR_POJO.getId());
        }
        notifyItemChanged(holder.getAdapterPosition(), YOUR_POJO);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface class like this;

```
public interface ItemSelectedListener{
    void onItemSelected(int selectedposition);
}
```

In your adapter initialize your interface;

```
    private List<ItemSelectedListener> mItemSelectedSubscribers = new ArrayList<ItemSelectedListener>();
```

Add this method in your adapter ;

```
public void subscribeItemSelection(ItemSelectedListenerlistener) {
        mItemSelectedSubscribers .add(listener);
    }
```

Set this loop in your click events;

```
for (ItemSelectedListener listener : mMediaSelectedSubscribers) {
    listener.onItemSelected(position);
                }
```

In your activity, implement your interface and you will set a implemented methods. this methods look like this;

```
int selectedPosition;
    @Override
        public void onMediaSelected(int position) {
            selectedPosition = position;
        }
```

When you do this you can use your selected position where you want in your activity

Hope this help!